# remove string which contains special character by python regular expression

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

my code:

```
s = '$ascv abs is good'
re.sub(p.search(s).group(),'',s)
```

ouput:

```
'$ascv abs is good'
```

the output what i want:

```
'abs is good'
```

I want to remove string which contains special character by python regular expression. I thought my code was right but the output is wrong.

How can i fix my code to make the output right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
invalid_chars = ['@'] # Characters you don't want in your text

# Determine if a string has any character you don't want
def if_clean(word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter in invalid_chars:
            return False
    return True

def clean_text(text):
    text = text.split(' ') # Convert text to a list of words
    text_clean = ''
    for word in text:
        if if_clean(word):
            text_clean = text_clean+' '+word
    return text_clean[1:]

# This will print 'abs is good'
print(clean_text('$ascv abs is good'))
```